# Use Apple ID for Login on Multiple Devices

Tags: ios, macos, apple-id

I have one Apple ID on my work computer, and home I use my personal Apple ID. Is it possible for me to use Apple Music on my work computer with my personal Apple ID? Would like to be able to listen to music while at the office.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - Yes.  Simply log into your Work Computer (using the personal Apple ID), and any purchases you made using that account will be visible.